# "Query response is nil without errors"

Tags: ios, blockchain, aion, pokt

I'm trying to get my AION balance using Pocket AION plugin in my iOS app, but I get "Query response is nil without errors". The code i have is

```swift
do {
  try? PocketAion.eth.getBalance(address: publicKey, subnetwork: "32", blockTag: BlockTag.init(block: .LATEST), handler: { (result, error) in
    if error != nil {
      print(error!)
      return
    }
    let conv = Double.init(result!) / Double(10000000000000000)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.showCount.text = conv.description
    }
  })
} catch {
  print("error, no count")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it came up as Nil was because the network nodes were syncing. The code works fine now!